# Fourth column in Fundation get pushed down

Tags: zurb-foundation

i have a problem with Foundation. I have four containers where to of them is shown as sidebar on the right on bigger screens. On smaller screens I want to *weave* them into the other content. My sections are as follows:

```
`<section class="column medium-8">
</section>
<aside class="column small-12 medium-4 authorDetails">
</aside>
<section class="column medium-8 small-12 shouldBeOnBottomOnSmall">
</section>
<aside class="column small-12 medium-4 authorDetails helloThere">
</aside>`
```

aside.helloThere gets pushed next to section.shouldBeOnBottomOnSmall on bigger screens. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The columns work great for adding widths to your layout but you need rows to make it stay in place. The row is a wrapper for your columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <section class="medium-12 columns">
```

http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/jPNRVK

BTW - if you are using  tags, make sure you have a heading inside it.

Comment: This still has the same problem. If you have a bit more text in the first field, the fourth field will be pushed down. [Explained in this picture](http://i.imgur.com/zi6m2gX.png)